# My EC2 Instance Disappeared but the Web App running on it is still running

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't ssh into my ec2 instance as I get connection timed out. I checked for my instances on the aws console, and I have no running instances. I have a web app / api running and accessible through the public ip of that ec2 instance, and I can still access it. Is it possible that I lost ownership of the instance somehow?

I'm not a premium user so I can't post in aws forums or contact them about this.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently my region was changed, and I didn't realize it only showed me instances of my selected region.

[image]

And the reason I couldn't ssh in was because my personal ip changed, but was not permitted by the security group inbound rule yet.

Comment: For most AWS services, all of the regions are operationally independent, for reliability reasons... so you usually only see what's in the specific region currently selected, and there is not really a concept of your account having a primary/default region though it's a reasonable assumption.  More about the differences, if you are curious, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33289160/1695906)  and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116302/83083).